# How to interleave two lists in python?

Tags: python

I have 2 python lists:

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b_list = ["a", "b"]
```

I want to interleave these two lists together into `c_list` such that `c_list` looks likes this:

```
[1, "a", 2, "b", 3]
```

How best to do it??

Comment: See the ```roundrobin``` function in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in thd docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
while a_list and b_list:
  result.append(a_list.pop(0))
  result.append(b_list.pop(0))
result.extend(a_list)
result.extend(b_list)
```